# Getting exception log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly

Tags: selenium, log4j

package ICICI;

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class ICICI_CareerHomePage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Starting Execution");
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Public//MessageCentre//InputFiles//chromedriver.exe");


        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        String useragent= "Mozilla/45.4.0 (Windows NT 6.1\\; WOW64) 
        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36 WFBTesting";

        options.addArguments("--user-agent=" +useragent);

        options.addArguments("--test-type");

        options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");

        options.addArguments("disable-infobars");

        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

        //driver.additional.capabilities={"chromeOptions":{"args":["--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1\\; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36 WFBTesting"]}};

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        System.out.println("ICICI Home Page Opened");
    }

}
```

I have written the above code but it is throwing the exception as:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

Comment: The exception you are getting has no connection with the actual error. If you look closely, the error that you should be trying to resolve is `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.`

Comment: @Amreeta Can you update us with the Selenium, ChromeDriver & Google Chrome version you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

You need to address a couple of things as below:

1. To work with Selenium 3.4.0, you need to download the latest chromedriver v2.29 from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and upgrade your Google Chrome to 58.x.Save the chromedriver in your machine and provide the absolute path while you mention `System.setProperty`
2. While mentioning the absolute path of the chromedriver either you provide single `/` (front slash) or you have to escape the back slash `\\`
3. The error logs which you see as `log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.` is because you have configured `log4j` to generate additional logs and write into a file for one of the Class files. That configuration still remains in your project level but you haven't taken care of the `log4j` settings in this Class file. Hence you see the `log4j:WARN` but they are harmless and you need not worry about them.
4. Here is your own working code with some simple tweaks in it:

   ```
       System.out.println("Starting Execution");
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
       DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
       ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
       String useragent= "Mozilla/45.4.0 (Windows NT 6.1\\; WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.59 Safari/537.36 WFBTesting";
       options.addArguments("--user-agent=" +useragent);
       options.addArguments("--test-type");
       options.addArguments("--allow-running-insecure-content");
       options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
       capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
       driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
       System.out.println("ICICI Home Page Opened");
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helps. :) really appreciate.